# Cookie and Session Variables creation / deletion

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have 2 separate PHP files, one which creates sessions and cookies and another which destroys them. I try loading one after the other by manually typing their URL in the browser and it doesn't seem to be working. (I've tried 'time ()' attribute inside cookie if that's your concern.)

test.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '1s'.$_SESSION['uname'] ;
echo '1c'.$_COOKIE['usrid'] ;
$_SESSION["uname"] = "green";
setcookie("usrid", 'blue', strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/");
echo '2s'.$_SESSION['uname'] ;
echo '2c'.$_COOKIE['usrid'] ;
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
setcookie("usrid", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), "/");
?>
```

I've tried reloading the pages again and again but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you know that the session wasn't destroyed?

Comment: reloading the test.php should give nothing after '1s' and '1c'. @MehdiBounya

Comment: But you are setting the cookie just right before printing them, of course they will have a value.

Comment: only after creation, it should appear, following '2c'. That's my logic. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention to the first echo, what browser are you using?

Comment: Also note, doing JUST `setcookie` won't set the value in the `$_COOKIE` var in the same script run. `$_COOKIE` will be set on the second run of the script after that cookie is passed back to the server.

Comment: Tried it on Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I just tried your code and it's working fine, are you sure it's not working, can you please update your question with the steps in details.

Comment: @IncredibleHat You're right, that should give cookie value following '1c' after a page reload. Even that's not happening.

Comment: I really don't know what else to add, because what you've shown as an example for a second script that clears those, they really should be gone when going to the other script. That is certainly not normal behavior ;) I wish I had more, but I've not seen this behavior before.

Comment: @MehdiBounya Seems like it's only me for whom the code is not working. I'll look into it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Oh, and for that first script.... doing an echo BEFORE setcookie... it really shouldn't even be making that cookie at all, and you should be getting a php warning about headers already output, blah blah blah.

Comment: @IncredibleHat My thought behind it is to get it to display value when the second script is not loaded. Just reloading the first one should display it. Isn't it right?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Thanks, I just got cookies working after deleting echo before initiation. Session still isn't.

Comment: Got it all sorted out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing an echo BEFORE setcookie... it really shouldn't even be making that cookie at all, and you should be getting a php warning about headers already output.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me.

If you want to check then please create 3 files

1. In this file just define variable for session and cookie

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["uname"] = "green";
setcookie("usrid", 'blue', strtotime( '+30 days' ), "/");
echo '2s'.$_SESSION['uname'] ;
echo "<br>";
echo '2c'.$_COOKIE['usrid'] ;
```

2. In this file do code for remove session and cookie

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION = array();
   session_destroy();
   setcookie("usrid", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), "/");
   ```
3. And in this last file add code for data retrieve

   print_r($_SESSION);
   print_r($_COOKIE);

Comment: Tried on different browsers with 3 files, still no luck.

Comment: Then not sure, what's the issue but its working for me for all browser